# Play! 2.0 and Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework-2.0

Did anybody try to get play 2.0 on GAE? Play is now based on sbt, technically [sbt-appengine-plugin](https://github.com/Yasushi/sbt-appengine-plugin) should work. And if you have tried, what is your datastore setup?

Comment: Many parts of the play framework can run on app engine, including Twirl (play templates) https://github.com/spray/twirl and play routing https://github.com/siderakis/playframework-appengine

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't beleive it will work as, if I'm not mistaken, GAE requires a *war* file, which Play 2.0 can't generate.

That will not be possible until Play 2.1 (as per current plan)

Comment: Actually, now it is not certain even if it will ever support GAE. see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/MtWcaaBN14E/discussion

Comment: Thanks for the info, its a pity but I can see why its almost impossible to add to GAE. Will probably use AWS or Heroku which I have used before and is very good.

Comment: App Engine now supports Google Compute Engine backends (which are full VMs), so you could use Akka on the backend and some non-Play framework on the frontend... of interest to anyone who chose Play because of the Akka foundation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Ninja Web Framework](http://www.ninjaframework.org) and the [Ninja Appengine](https://github.com/ninjaframework/ninja-appengine) module. One of the main reasons why we started Ninja was App Engine support.

Comment: Ninja looks interesting. but need some documentation. For example Ajax tags.