# Does GAE module work with PlayFramework 2.0?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, playframework

I read in the documentation that play modules only work with 1.x version of play-framework. But I found there are lot of new versions of the gae-module, does they support 2.0 version of play-framework?

Also, I found this in the google groups in which Pascal(who developed and maintained gae module), is saying that he will soon write the module for play2.0. But the thread is of december 2011. Does it started support play2.0?

Also I would like to know if anyone deployed a play2.0 application to google-appengine and how, would be fine even if it is done without the gae-module, directly using appengine-sdk)?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once Google App Engine implement Servlet 3.0 (tracked on this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091)) and Play 2.0 implement WAR deployment (tracker on this [bug](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/8-war-packaging) it should be technically possible to deploy Play 2.0 application on Google App Engine.

Comment: There is this war plugin which is currently working for Play 2.x. https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/ Since it says they support servlet engines 2.x, Would I be be able to use it on app engine as long as I don't use features like web sockets etc?

Answer (score 1):

No, the gae module does not work with Play 2.0.

As you can read on the [module's web page](http://www.playframework.org/modules/gae):

> This module is for the Play 1.x series only.

Also, please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378719/play-2-0-and-google-app-engine) and [this thread](https://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/32d59c69a04dd781?pli=1).

So, in conclusion: Play 2.0 does not work on Google App Engine, and maybe it never will. But you can use Play 1.x with the gae module, which is still just fine to choose for a new project.

Comment: Is there any workaround to deploy play2.0 application to appengine. can we do it directly using appengine-sdk ?

Comment: the only workaround would be to build a module yourself that allows GAE to interact with Play. I doubt it would be built by the core team (like the Play1.x module was), as since then a lot of PaaS vendors support Play natively and do not require the major limitations of GAE with Play.