# Play framework 3.0 with scala 2.13 How to deploy on Google app engine

Tags: scala, google-app-engine, playframework

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>default</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java17</runtime>
    <instance-class>F2</instance-class>
    <automatic-scaling>
        <target-cpu-utilization>0.65</target-cpu-utilization>
        <min-instances>1</min-instances>
        <max-instances>5</max-instances>
        <max-concurrent-requests>50</max-concurrent-requests>
    </automatic-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```

getting not found error with gae url

how to deploy on Google app engine?

Comment: Are you sure that GAE has support for Play 3? It seems that it only has support for Play 1.x. [Does GAE module work with PlayFramework 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913782/does-gae-module-work-with-playframework-2-0). Besides that, you should provide debugging details about your problem, such as log error messages, the configuration you used, etc