# Is it possible to use Eclipse IDE and GAE plugin to develop and deploy Scala Applications with PlayFramework?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, scala, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to use Eclipse IDE and GAE plugin to develop and deploy Scala Applications with PlayFramework v2.0?
Also there is some outdated GAE module for PlayFramework v1.0.
Any instructions or links? Or only possible to deploy manually (like this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp) ?

Comment: There are [at least two answered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378719/play-2-0-and-google-app-engine) which also address your case. Play 2.x applications will NOT run on GAE at all, due to highly restricted nature of Google's platform (i.e. Servlet API, SDK limitations, etc.) So this is not just about tools or Eclipse plugins. Play 2.x is conceptually different from Play 1.x.

Comment: @coffeesnake Yes, you right. I've read here  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/play-framework there are some troubles with GAE and Playframework 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no solution for working Playframework 2.0 applications on GAE for the time I'm writing. 
Needless to say that any tools do not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [ScalaGWT](https://github.com/scalagwt/scalagwt-scala)? It works quite well and can be debugged easily in Eclipse as well. There are a few samples hosted on GitHub as well.

Answer (score -1):

I guess yes, make a **play app using play console**, **add gae support** to it by adding **gae module** to it and then **eclipsify** it. While writing this i assume you already have gone through play v1.0 docs. If not i suggest go through playframework.org first.